# What are perf cache events meaning?

Tags: c, linux, perf

I am trying to figure out why a modified C program is running faster than its non modified counter part (I am adding very few lines of code to perform some additional work). In this context, I suspect "*cache effects*" to be the main explanation (instruction cache). Thus I reach the `perf` (https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) profiling tool but unfortunately I am not able to understand the meaning of its outputs regarding cache misses.

Several events about cache are provided:

```
  cache-references                                   [Hardware event]
  cache-misses                                       [Hardware event]
  L1-dcache-loads                                    [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-stores                                   [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-store-misses                             [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-prefetches                               [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-prefetch-misses                          [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-loads                                    [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-prefetches                               [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-prefetch-misses                          [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-loads                                          [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-load-misses                                    [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-stores                                         [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-store-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-prefetches                                     [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-prefetch-misses                                [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-prefetches                                    [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-prefetch-misses                               [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  branch-loads                                       [Hardware cache event]
  branch-load-misses                                 [Hardware cache event]
  node-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  node-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  node-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  node-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  node-prefetches                                    [Hardware cache event]
  node-prefetch-misses                               [Hardware cache event]
```

Where can I find explanation about these fields ? cache-misses event is always smaller than other events. What does this event measure ?

How to interpret the 26,760 L1-icache-load-misses for ls vs the 5,708 cache-misses in the following example ?

```
perf stat -e L1-icache-load-misses ls
caches  caches~  out

 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

            26,760 L1-icache-load-misses                                       

       0.002816690 seconds time elapsed



perf stat -e cache-misses ls
caches  caches~  out

 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

             5,708 cache-misses                                                

       0.002822122 seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: I found this useful: [Determining whether an application has poor cache performance \- Red Hat Developer](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/03/10/determining-whether-an-application-has-poor-cache-performance-2/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You seem to think that the `cache-misses` event is the sum of all other kind of cache misses (`L1-dcache-load-misses`, and so on). That is actually not true.

the `cache-misses` event represents the number of memory access that could not be served by any of the cache.

I admit that perf's documentation is not the best around.

However, one can learn quite a lot about it by reading (assuming that you already have a good knowledge of how a CPU and a performance monitoring unit work, this is clearly not a computer architecture course) the doc of the perf_event_open() function:

http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/perf_event_open.html

For example, by reading it you can see that the `cache-misses` event showed by perf list corresponds to `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES`

Comment: See also [How does Linux perf calculate the cache-references and cache-misses events](//stackoverflow.com/q/55035313) for some basics about some generic events mapping to HW events on recent Intel CPUs.

Answer (score 34):

Some answers:

- `L1` is the Level-1 cache, the smallest and fastest one. `LLC` on the other hand refers to the last level of the [cache hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Multi-level_caches), thus denoting the largest but slowest cache.
- `i` vs. `d` distinguishes instruction cache from data cache. Only L1 is split in this way, other caches are shared between data and instructions.
- `TLB` refers to the [translation lookaside buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer), a cache used when mapping virtual addresses to physical ones.
- Different TLB counters depending on whether the named address referred to an instruction or some data.
- For all data access, different counters are kept depending on whether the given memory location was read, written, or prefetched (i.e. retrieved for reading at some later time).
- The number of misses indicates how often a given item of data was accessed but *not* present in the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you using this tool ? How do you explain the cache-misses event referred to as a Hardware Event and not Hardware Cache Event. I though it was the sum of others but not at all.

Comment: And moreover what's the difference between "loads" and "prefetches" ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva: I'm not using `perf` myself, so I have little actual experience. In particular, I'm unsure what the `cache-misses` event actually describes, compared to all the hardware cache events. I'm not totaly sure about prefetches either: there is a way to trigger prefetches at the application level as well as automatic prefetches of data access predicted by the hardware. Either or both of these might be what the prefetch counters actually describe. `perf` documentation mentions manufacturer specs for further details, but I haven't yet found the relevant sections.

Comment: @ManuelSelva a "load" is when your program executes a load instruction to retrieve memory.  A "prefetch" is when the processor guesses that you're going to load memory in the near future, and fetches it ahead of time.  That way when your program does use the memory it will already be in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

According to [perf tutorial](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial), *Performance Monitoring Unit (PMU) events* or *hardware events* refer to those events which can be mapped directly to CPU specific events for a CPU vendor. But the *hardware cache events* refer to some hardware events monikers provided by `perf`, which may be mapped to actual events provided by the CPU. For the list of `perf`'s cache events use `perf list cache` in Linux terminal.