# which cache level does cache-misses consider?

Tags: multicore, perf

As you know, there is an event in Perf called cache-misses. there are two or three levels of cache in multi-core systems. May i know cache which of them is considered by cache-misses event?

Comment: Yes, you may. The usual way of finding out would be to consult [relevant documentation](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are perf cache events meaning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601474/what-are-perf-cache-events-meaning)

Comment: What is your CPU?